How Do i prevent wkwebview loading full screen?
I am loading an i frame url in webview but when i click on play button it is loading to full screen but i need to stop that
Here i need to load the url with in the webview frame only it should not go to full screen mode
I have tried the following code but still i am getting the full screen mode.
`   override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    // Set up the WKWebViewConfiguration
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
    } else {
        configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = false
    }
    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: 300, height: 250))
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    
    // Load the iframe
    loadIframe()
}

func loadIframe() {
        let iframeURL = "https://instaview.instavc.com/player/embed_player.php?vid=1040&width=300&height=250&autoplay=no"
        let htmlString = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body, html {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }
                iframe {
                    border: none;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }
                video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <iframe id="videoPlayer" src="\(iframeURL)" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
            <script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                    var iframe = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
                    iframe.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function() {
                        if (document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
                            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
                        }
                    }, false);
                });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
        """
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    }

`
The above class is the sample class i have tried to load the url in webview
but i need to prevent the video loading into the full screen
